# Can a foreigner rent guns in a shooting range in metro-DC area?

Tags: usa, washington-dc, firearms

Can a European visitor rent a gun in a range near the metro-DC area?

Unlike the websites of ranges located in New York, the Virginia/Maryland ranges don't seem to specify whether tourists can rent guns or not.

Comment: Probably in Virginia. Maryland is much more restrictive generally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually if you google [firarm rental virginia](https://www.google.com/maps/search/firearm+rental+virginia/@37.7997315,-76.7572197,8z/data=!3m1!4b1) you will come up with a few options including:

- [Silver Eagle Group](http://silvereaglegroup.com/range-use/rentals/) in Ashburn, VA
- [Blue Ridge Arsenal](http://blueridgearsenal.com/range-rates/) in Chantilly, VA
- [Gilbert Indoor Range](http://www.gilbertindoorrange.com/beginner-package.html) in Rockville, MD

and the list goes on.  The way that rentals work in most places that I've looked at is that you rent a gun but you have to buy the ammo at the range.  Most only require that you have a current valid government issued ID but not the restriction on that it has to be a state or federal government of the United States.

Answer (score 4):

From various [reviews online on yelp](http://www.yelp.com/biz/maryland-small-arms-range-upper-marlboro-2?osq=indoor+shooting+range), literally you can start shooting with just:

- a form of identification
- a credit card.

While there are laws about owning guns, generally a range you're just using someone else's, under strict supervision.

One other person mentioned that [at a Virginia range](https://foursquare.com/v/nra-shooting-range/4b535321f964a520719727e3) you needed an extra 15-30 minutes for rules of the range and testing to get your range card, if it's your first time there.

Hope that's what you're after.

Comment: There have been a bunch of sad folks that have chosen to off themselves *at* gun ranges, so expect a bit more scrutiny if you arrive alone.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany There is a lot cheaper ways of doing it.

Comment: @Karlson Doubt they are looking to save money :)